# JUnit 5 tests are not recognizable in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, junit5

I'm trying to convert to JUnit 5 version inside IntelliJ CE 2017.2.3 and experiencing the following:

[image]

Same tests ran with JUnit 4, the error manifests itself only with the upgrade.

The pom.xml portion:

```
   <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

These Java snippets might be relevant:

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it really easier to take screenshots and edit them into a SO question instead of simply copy-pasting the relevant text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178063#comment=27-2389650). Please upgrade to [latest IDE version](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download) which has updated JUnit libraries and should be working fine.

Comment: How does one upgrade?  Does upgrade mean completely wiping out the existing version and re-installing the new one or can I update from within the existing IDE?

Comment: For major version upgrade (2017.2 -> 2017.3) you should download full distribution from the site. On the first launch it will ask you to import settings from previous installation. You can also consider using [Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app) for managing installed JetBrains IDEs.

Comment: Indeed, upgrading to 2017.3.2 and manually fixing `a bunch` of compile errors due to JUnit 5 vs JUnit 4 repackaging incompatibilities alleviated the issue.  Wouldn't it be intelligent and nice of IntelliJ IDEA to suggest those refactorings while discovering JUnit 5 on the classpath?

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon there are JUnit4->Junit5 quick-fixes. If you find any such specific cases, please file them at  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA Thanks.

Comment: I just discovered a new behavior - after one adds a test, IDEA reverts to not recognizing it again.  Looks like running Maven `test` target then makes it to recognize it.  Is that a feature or a bug?